# SQL Query: LIKE

Tags: mysql, database, sql-like

I have a query where I want to view names of carparks (cp_name) that are near the iona building (nearbyFacilities). The query works without the last line but it displays all carparks. Any idea how to just get the results related to the word iona?

```
SELECT CP_Name.Name, CP_Location.nearbyFacilities
FROM CP_Name
INNER JOIN CP_Location 
ON CP_Name.CarparkID = CP_Location.CarparkID 
WHERE nearbyFacilities LIKE `%iona%`  -- this line doesn't work
```

Comment: `like '%iona%'`

Comment: i had quotes but the site turned into a shaded area

Comment: See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491)

Comment: @sarahjane I just tried to edit, and noticed that you had _backticks_, not quotes, around `LIKE`.  Use quotes (the key immediately to the right of the semicolon).

Comment: such a simple solution that I missed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help, I think I've seen 3-4 of this type of question today, so it must be a common beginner error.